# Disable shortcut/shotkeys of browser in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, browser, shortcut

I am trying to add some shortcut handlers like Ctrl+B in my Silverlight application.
However, in IE when we press the Ctrl+B, it comes out a child window of " Organize Favorings". Is it possible to disable these browser shortcuts with Silverlight?

Many many thanks!

Mrainy

Comment: did u find any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm [not sure you can](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/19032.aspx) judging by what I've read. You may be able to hack it with javascript code on the page that passes it on to the silverlight application, however. (See [javascript/silverlight interop](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/06/Silverlight-and-JavaScript-Interop-Basics.aspx))

Comment: Thanks Brad, as mentioned in the MSDN, "Most keystrokes that a browser hosts interprets as commands are shortcut or accelerator keystrokes, and when this happens the keystrokes are not passed as key events to Silverlight". So it seems like we don't have too much choices.

Comment: I don't understand how this reply solves the problem. Why is it accepted as answer? I tried to use Javascript to catch keys, but Javascript keydown and keypress events cannot be used when Silverlight object is active. (In my case there is just a silverlight page, and no additional html objects, so keydown/keypress events are live only on page load before I activate Silverlight object by clicking on it.) Is it only my fault?

Comment: @AlKepp: My understanding is it's accepted because it's not possible. I've linked to a silverlight forum post mentioning explicitly that you can not read the keys. However, if you do find a work-around, please feel free to post it and I will be more than happy to bring light of it and encourage that answer be the acceptable one. -- (EDIT: Given the browser isn't handing off keystrokes like ctrl+b to silverlight, but IS handing them off to JS, it should be possible with an interop work-around though)

Comment: AFAIK Javascript doesn't run in IE when Silverlight runs. I mean if you have a Silverlight object active (focused), no keys are sent to JavaScript. So, AFAIK, JS workaround isn't possible in Internet Explorer.

Comment: @AlKepp: Based on my findings, regardless of activity, IE interprets all keystrokes and sends them to the appropriate (activated) applet/plugin when necessary (which is why it's selective about Ctrl+B (and other) shortcuts and sending them off to the silverlight application). It should be possible to catch them with both JS and Silverlight, but I'm basing this off only things I've read from googling/silverlight.net forums. If I get time today I'll write of a demo project to test and see if I can't get it working.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use common shortcuts in your application perhaps you should consider running it in  Out of Browser mode.

You can find out more about OOB on the MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd550721(v=vs.95).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882515.aspx

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I have to use this application in Browser mode.